# webkit focus behaviour on Android 4.0.4

Tags: javascript, android, css, forms, webkit

I am seeing some strange behaviour on a pair of input fields in Webkit 534.30 on Android 4.0.4. On focus in the field, the user is unable to click the page and hide the keyboard i.e. gets 'stuck in the field. It works fine in Chrome and in the stock browser on a Sony Xperia S but not the stock ICS browser on a Galaxy S2.

Is anyone aware of a known issue with input focus/blur in this version of webkit or whether there is a better way to set input field focus than:

The code just uses:

```
$('#input_id').blur(function ()
{
    // update some other parts of DOM
});
```

and

```
$('#input_id').focus(function ()
{
    $(this).val("");
});
```

Is there a better way to do this for mobile browsers? This issue seems isolated to this particular build of Android on the S2.

I have tried disabling all Javascript and debugging using Adobe Edge Inspect but this hasn't thrown up anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by having non numeric characters in the input fields with their attribute 'type' set to "tel". It seems that particular build of webkit would really rather you didn't do that.